# How to Iterate Through GroupBy - Getting Duplicate Key Error

Tags: c#

I can't figure out how to do this right.  I want to be able to iterate this dictionary because it's for my unit test and so each pair for me is important to have in here

```
var invalidPageNumberAndSize = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"0", ""},
    {"", "0"},
    {"abc", ""},
    {"", "abc"}
}.GroupBy(p => p.Key);

foreach (var invalidPagingCombination in invalidPageNumberAndSize)
{

    Console.WriteLine(invalidPagingCombination.Key + " " + invalidPagingCombination);
}
```

Comment: You're adding two dictionary items with an empty string as the key.

Comment: As I think eddie_cat was trying to say, you can not have 2 entries in a `Dictionary` with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

You are entering two keys in your dictionary that are empty:

```
 {"", "0"},
```

and

```
 {"", "abc"}
```

change this to

```
{"foo", "abc"}
```

and the error will go away.  A dictionary can only have 1 instance of each key.  You could also use a List of Tuples if you needed to:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("", "apple"));
list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("", "zebra"));
```

Comment: @CoffeeAddict  BTW, decision on whether to use Tuples or KeyValuePairs really depends on your usage.  This is a good link for the test between the two:  http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple-keyvaluepair.  Usually, Tuples is a better route to go in terms of performance due to KeyvaluePairs being implemented as a struct.

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection of `KeyValuePair` instead of dictionary:

```
var invalidPageNumberAndSize = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("0", ""),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", "0"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("abc", ""),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", "abc")
}.GroupBy(p => p.Key);
```